# Prolog trying to make fixed size empty list

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to make a list in prolog with these dimensions:

```
[
[[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]],
[[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]],
[[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]],
[[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]],
[[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]],
[[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]],
[[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]],
[[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]],
[[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]]
]
```

So a list containing 9 lists containing 2 lists of 9 elements.

I tried the following:

```
createEmptyView(ReturnList, Size) :-
  length(ReturnList, Size),
  ( for(Y, 1, Size), param(ReturnList, Size) do
      Row is ReturnList[Y],
      length(Row, 2),
      Xlist = Row[0],
      Ylist = Row[1],
      length(Xlist, Size),
      length(Ylist, Size)
  ).
```

Where Size = 9 and ReturnList is the output.

The retrieving of the Xlist and Ylist is where it goes wrong.
I also tried the following to extract them:

```
[Xlist, Ylist] is Row,
Row = [Xlist, Ylist | _ ],
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you want a 9x2x9 uninstantiated matrix?

Answer (score 1):

```
mylength(X,Y):-
    length(Y,X).

list_sizes(Size,List):-
    maplist(mylength(Size),List).
```

Then query:

```
?- length(List,9), list_sizes(2,List), maplist(list_sizes(9),List).
```

You could make this shorter be not having the helper mylength/2 and use a lambda expression using library yall for example.